# Scrolling with div to certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code which works fine, but when i scroll down, my div is reaching the footer and dont stop. How can I stop scrolling with page at certain point?

```
(function($) {
    var element = $('#div'),
        originalY = element.offset().top;

    var topMargin = 20;

    element.css('position', 'relative');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        element.stop(false, false).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalY
                    ? 0
                    : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        }, 300);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/660884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple multiple ternary operator to define which position do you want to stop at. This example have 2 point of stop, between stopTop 1 and stopTop 2. If scrollTop reach the stopTop1 then it will freeze on that position until scroll top pass the stopTop2 :

`top : scrollTop < originalY
      ? 0
      : scrollTop > stopTop1 && scrollTop < stopTop2
      ? stopTop1
      : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin`

Here the the code that you can try :
[myjsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/firhatsungkar/dx5t28Ln/)